# MySQL query: blog entry has comments or not

Tags: mysql, sql

How expensive is this query?

Lets say for example if I don't have a field called `total_comments` in my `blog` table. All I want to know is the blog has comments or not.

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT true FROM comments WHERE blog_id = b.id) as has_comments FROM blogs b
```

How else could this be achieved?

Comment: It depends on how often you execute the query.

Comment: also depends (a lot) whether you have an index on the blog_id field of the comments table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: Ah...I've reread your original query. When I first read it, I thought that you were only retrieving this for a single blog, but now I see that you're retrieving for every blog record.

This might be inefficient, though I'm not sure.  I suppose it depends on how good MySQL is at dealing with that subquery.

Below is probably the most straightforward approach:

```
SELECT
    blogs.blog_id,
    COUNT(comments.blog_id)
FROM blogs
LEFT OUTER JOIN comments on
    comments.blog_id = blogs.blog_id
GROUP BY
    blogs.blog_id
```

Of course, this gives you a count, which is more information that was asked for, but this will probably be pretty efficient if you have an index on blog_id.

Another alternative is to union together a result of the  blogs that have comments with another result of the blogs that don't have comments.

```
SELECT blog_id, true
FROM blogs
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT true
        FROM comments
        WHERE
            comments.blog_id = blogs.blog_id
    )

UNION ALL

SELECT blog_id, false
FROM blogs
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT true
        FROM comments
        WHERE
            comments.blog_id = blogs.blog_id
    )
```

Comment: Thanks it going to be interesting to see the performance between count+group vs exists. And in your second solution you put subquery in the where where mine is in the select. Will have to do some benchmarks here. I am going to mark this as the correct solution. But will update this question with the benchmarks later this week.

Comment: @Contra - I'm not sure about MySQL, but I believe that in older versions of SQL Server, you would get better performance by putting an "exists" condition in the where clause rather than as a column in the result. I believe that modern versions of SQL Server are intelligent enough to optimize the query either way, though.